# GTK Manual installation on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: installation, gtk

I posted in other stack exchange programming forum but since it was not the appropriate forum I am reposting it. I do not have internet in one of my pc where I want to install GTK. I have internet in other pc, so I want to download and manually install in my PC. Can someone please explain step by step procedure. The details of my PC are windows 7 32 bit. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the installer from internet and just install it as usual.
you can visit these sites

http://gtkwindows.blogspot.in/2012/09/compiling-first-gtk-program.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/

Answer (score 0):

For Gtk3 - http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php

Basically comes down to installing [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) and using their package manager.